# Installing kivy in venv on Ubuntu

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to install kivy. According to this [guide](https://realpython.com/mobile-app-kivy-python/) I used the commands:

```
$ python3 -m venv my_kivy_project
$ cd my_kivy_project
$ source bin/activate
$ python -m pip install kivy
```

This installation failed so I have found [this](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-linux.html) guide for Ubuntu.
I did the steps again, with the first step (according to the guide) being

```
$ python -m pip install --upgrade --user pip setuptools virtualenv
```

It failed again. (

> Failed building wheel for kivy

)

So, I wanted to try `Nightly wheel installation`, but the links are dead (`Error 404 not found`)
So, I wanted to try `PPA`
After:
`$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kivy-team/kivy`

I have this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 11, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties import SoftwareProperties, shortcut_handler
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 67, in <module>
    from gi.repository import Gio
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . import _gi
ImportError: cannot import name '_gi' from 'gi' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py)
```

Could you help me with the installation on Linux (Ubuntu 18.04)?
Now I'm using Python 3.7 (but I tried 3.8 as well).
Installation of kivy globally worked, but I need to install it in `venv`.
I don't want manually install kivy from source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kivy is built from C sources when installed with pip, and it requires a compiler, Python headers, and mesa (OpenGL) headers. Unfortunately the docs on their website aren't very helpful in this case. These packages were enough to make it work on a clean Ubuntu 18.04 machine:

```
$ apt update
$ apt install python3 python3-venv python3-pip python3-dev build-essential libgl1-mesa-dev
```

and then you can

```
$ python3 -m venv my_kivy_project
$ cd my_kivy_project
$ source bin/activate
(my_kivy_project) $ pip install kivy
```

which would still print

```
"Failed building wheel for kivy"
```

but `kivy` is installed now – you don't really need the `wheel` to use it:

```
(my_kivy_project) $ pip freeze | grep Kivy
Kivy==1.11.1
Kivy-Garden==0.1.4

(my_kivy_project) $ python
>>> import kivy
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in …/.kivy/logs/kivy_20-10-12_2.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "…/site-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
…
```

if you need the wheel for some reason, or just want to get rid of the message, installing the `wheel` package and then reinstalling `kivy` should do the trick:

```
(my_kivy_project) $ pip install wheel
(my_kivy_project) $ pip install --ignore-installed kivy
```

Comment: I tried it but
`$ pip freeze | grep Kivy
Kivy-Garden==0.1.4`
gives me only Kivy-Garden

Comment: Hmm, is there any other error message other than that *wheel* one? Not all of them are in red. Perhaps you're missing another library…

Comment: I pasted the output [here](https://pastebin.com/9EKkzegM)

Comment: It works now. I have to install a few apt packages (I don't remember their names, but I found there in the output that I pasted). I remember only `python3.7-dev` was needed. So it works with python3.7

Comment: Yeah, it seems that 3.6 is the default version in Ubuntu 18.04, so `python3-dev` installs headers for that version… Glad it works now.